# Can't comment and other problems with Cobol

Tags: cobol

Currently learning Cobol in a course in Uni and there are several errors to my code that simply baffles me.

1) I can't comment on anything pass line 1. I put the * in col7 and it still doesn't work.

2) There seems to be a problem with all of my IF statements that I can't pinpoint. Specifically, it keeps telling me what ELSE is doing there. Also the compiler keeps telling me that the variable 'ohour-ihour', or any variables I use in COMPUTE, doesn't exist.

It would be really helpful if anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong :(

```
02 IN.
   03 ihour pic 99.
   03 imin pic 99.
02 OUT.
   03 ohour pic 99.
   03 omin pic 99.
...
IF ihour<ohour
   COMPUTE thour=ohour-ihour.
ELSE
   COMPUTE thour=ihour-ohour.
END-IF.
```

Comment: Thanks. Did you resolve the thing with the comment lines?

Comment: No, Thank You. I solved the else problem thanks to you. As for the comments I used *> in col 7 and 8 respectively.

Comment: The traditional (fixed-format) COBOL program layout requires `*` in column 7 for comments. Some compilers support a free-format layout (code can start in column 1) and there the `*>` is used to start a comment. Where supported, `*>` is also possible for inline comments, comments after some code and on the same line. You may have read about free-format comments and tried them in a fixed-format compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing you can't do is use words which are "reserved", which mean something specific to COBOL, for user-defined names. An example from your code is `IN`.

There are few hyphenated reserved-words, so a good way to avoid accidental use (now or if added to the language later) is to not use "one word" user-defined names. In fact, it is good practice, as in most languages, to use good, descriptive, used-defined names.

Another problem in your code is the use of full-stop/period. The `.` you have used within an `IF` has terminated the `IF`, so the `ELSE` is invalid.

As mentioned, data-names are generally hyphenated through practice, `-` is valid in a user-defined name and is used in much the same way (conventionally) as other languages use `_`. So when you have written `ohour minus ihour` as `ohour-ihour`, you haven't actually done that, but you've used a user-defined name, `ohour-ihour`, instead, which obviously isn't defined.

```
02 some-nice-descriptive-name.
   03 ihour pic 99.
   03 imin pic 99.
02 some-othe-nice-descriptive-name.
   03 ohour pic 99.
   03 omin pic 99.
...
IF ihour < ohour
   COMPUTE thour = ohour - ihour
ELSE
   COMPUTE thour = ihour - ohour
END-IF
.
```

Try the above instead. Only use full-stop/period where needed. Review COBOL questions here to get some ideas of common advice, practice and style.

You haven't included an example of the failing comment, so I can't comment on that. Show an example, and let us know compiler and OS.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use *> to comment line instead of *.

The asterisk character is can be used only in fixed format on column 7. 
It seems you are not using fixed format but free format. So you have to use combination of two characters *> as it is written in COBOL standard. Pages 22 and 23

http://www.cobolstandard.info/wg4/open/WD1-10-pdf.zip

or see:

http://www.opencobol.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=612&forum=1

Comment: You've pickled your first link. Can you edit to fix that please? Not sure of your evidence for use of free format, beyond the comment not working...

Comment: Tahnk you. The link has been corrected. Open Cobol (GNU Cobol) is very strict. If you are using free format you cannot use  just * character because * cannot be used in program-text area. Only floating indicators are allowed in program text area one of them is *> comment indicator . Other compilers are more benevolent and allow to use just *.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the link. If it turns out that OP is using GNU COBOL and compiling as free-format, then fair enough. GNU COBOL is not so much strict, as sensible. If using freeformat, why would you want a multiplication sign from a `COMPUTE` to potentially become a comment? As to guessing the question, can you make anything of the "pas(t) line 1" part, which would then give you a good shot a being right (and an Upvote). Solely assertions, I don't go for :-)

Comment: Your answer helped me. I stopped  coding COBOL about 20 years ago, back at those times * in column 7 was enough, only fixed-mode was allowed.